# Replace current home Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, site

I've inherited a SP Online site and would like to create a new site collection to replace the existing collection. Is there actually a way to do this? Or will I need to just tweak the existing site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the root site collection which is a little different in that you can't recreate it once it's deleted.

You'll need to open a support ticket with Microsoft to do this.  It might take some time - these guys are kind of slow (as in, "methodical") but they'll be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

you have two options

1.- Request a new site

2.- Clear your current site

Answer (score 0):

you've the ability to delete and create site collections when needed, please check this link for the steps to create a new site collection and also the steps to delete a site collection 
you must be either a Office 365 global admin or SharePoint admin

[Create or delete a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-delete-a-site-collection-3a3d7ab9-5d21-41f1-b4bd-5200071dd539)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new site collection if you are a global admin . IF you want the content of existing site collection , you can backup the content of this site collection using file explore and copy to your new site collection .